# Howcan I apply the material changes I did for a cube?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

The material on the right is golden but the cube is not.

[image: Material from a cube]

Comment: I pressed on TAB to change to edit mode then I clicked on the right in the material on select and then on assign but then when changing back to object mode I see that no changes have been made. The cube still gray and not golden like in the preview.

Comment: The material only takes effect in rendered mode. Try rendering your cube to see the material

Answer (score 0):

change view mode from solid to material to see shaders in viewport[image]